# WM_GETTEXT returns text separated with nulls

Tags: python, win32gui

```
import time
import win32gui
import win32con

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    buf = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(255)
    window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window)
    control = win32gui.FindWindowEx(window, 0, 'Edit', None)
    length = win32gui.SendMessage(control, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 255, buf)
    result = buf[:length]
    print('Title: ', win32gui.GetWindowText(window))
    print(str(buf[:length*2], "UTF_8")
```

Why it returns string separated with nulls? When I've tried just `buff[:length]` I had half of my string because of that nulls

```
bytearray(b'H\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x9dL\x03E\x888P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xedL\x03\xa9\xc4\xffb\xa0\tO\x00j\x8c\x1bZ\xa04\xc6\x02IP\x12\x8d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0X?\x03\xed`\x05\x89\xa0n\xfb\x02.\x02\xea\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0*X\x00\xf4b\x9c\xf9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd6\x8d\x02\x98?n\xb2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xcc\x02\xbey\xee\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

edit:

```
result = buf.tobytes()[:length*2:2]
print(result.decode("UTF-8"))
```

The code follow work as I wanted but I'm not sure It has been written correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting back from the Win32 API is a UTF-16 string.  Each character is 16-bits, so that's why it appears as if a null byte is in between each ascii when viewed as a byte array.

This is the correct way to interpret that string:

```
length = win32gui.SendMessage(control, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 255, buf)
result = buf[0:length*2]
text = result.decode("utf-16")
```

Your solution manages to work with a utf-8 decode because you are skipping over all the null chars.  That works fine, but will generate weird results (and possibly throw an exception) as soon as unicode characters are typed typed into that edit control.

Comment: Using your code I've got following error `AttributeError: 'memoryview' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Edit:
I used buf.tobytes().decode("UTF-16") and It works

Comment: I was using python 3.  I suspect you are on python 2.  Glad it worked for you.